# Point two variables to the same value in Python

Tags: python, reference

I know Python does not work with references, unlike Perl and others, but is it possible to create a simple variable whose values are linked, because they reference the same memory address? I know shallow copies of lists and dictionaries contain values that reference the same address.

```
>>> foo = 1
>>> bar = foo
>>> bar = 0
>>> foo
1
>>> foo = [1,2]
>>> bar = foo
>>> bar[1] = 0
>>> foo
[0,2]
```

*Cf.* in Perl

```
$ref = 1
$foo = \$ref
$bar = $foo
print $$bar //gives 1
$$foo = 0
print $$bar //gives 0
```

The reason why is that I am curious to how could it be done/hacked in Python.
To give a concrete example is that I would have liked to have given a class two "synonymous" attributes. 
I suppose that one could pull off a shenanigan like this (untested, sorry if wrong) by masking the second value:

```
class fake:
   def __init__(self,template):
       self.ref = template # keep alive
       self.__dict___ = template.__dict__
       self.__class___ = template.__class__
   def __getitem__(self):
       return self.ref.__getitem__
   def __setitem__(self,value):
       self.ref.__setitem__(value)
```

But that is not quite in the spirit of what I was curious about, but if a hack is the only way, I'll go for that and would love to know the best way.

Comment: In Python you would store the value in some object that you can reference.  For instance, you could put it in a list as the sole element, e.g. `[x]`, then use references to the list.  Or you could put it in a `dict`, or create a `class` for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just create an `@property` function that has the second name, but returns the first value?

```
class C:
    def __init__(self):
        self.attr1 = 12345

    @property
    def synonym(self):
        return self.attr1

    @synonym.setter
    def synonym(self, value):
        self.attr1 = value
```

This would let references to `synonym` be passed through to `attr1`.

Comment: Why was this answer downvoted? I assume something is wrong, but I am not overly familiar with the @property decorator.

Comment: I ended up using this solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change `immutable` objects. You can only reassign reference.

```
foo = bar = 1
bar = 0
```

Here you doesn't destroy `1` in memory, this is what immutability about, you just reassign `bar` point to `0`.

```
foo = bar = [1,2] 
bar[1] = 100
```

Here you change referenced object in memory.

```
>>> b = 1
>>> id(b)
15216984
>>> b = 2
>>> id(b)
15216960  # reference points to another object
>>> a = [1,2]
>>> id(a)
139917071841904
>>> a[0] = 100
>>> id(a)
139917071841904 # object is the same, therefore all references pointed to it will show changes
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a way to 'hack' it with deepcopy.

```
from copy import deepcopy
foo = [1,2]
bar = deepcopy(foo)
bar[1] = 0
print bar, foo
```

Check [here](http://www.python-course.eu/deep_copy.php) for explanation

Comment: No need for deep copy here, they will still reference the same list